# React js, How to get selected product name by id

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, babeljs

I need is to display selected product details, I am using React and Redux:
After selecting one product, in my ProductDetails page should be shown details of selected product. How should I properly make it in order to get and show product details

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { asyncConnect } from 'redux-connect';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as productActions from 'redux/modules/products';

@asyncConnect([{
  promise: ({ store: { dispatch, getState }, params }) => {
    dispatch(productActions.load({ id: params.prodId }, getState()));
  }
}])
@connect(
  state => ({
    products: state.products.items
  }),
  {
    ...productActions
  }
)
export default class ProductDetails extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    products: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    products: []
  };

  state = {
    products: []
  }

  render() {
    const { products } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <h1>Product details</h1>
            <div className="col-xs-12">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-4">
                  <div className="panel panel-default">
                      <div className="panel-body">
                        <p>{products.name}</p>// show selected product name
                        <p>{products.description}<p> // show selected product description
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, it was very easy: {products[0].name} and {products[0].description}

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem, it was very easy:

```
{products[0].name}
```

and

```
{products[0].description}
```